# i have array inside usestate and i changed value from function but dosnt work - react native hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

i use react native hooks for project but i have strange error 
i have array inside usestate and i changed value from function after this i want use value of array from another function but value is old value

```
  const addscore=()=>{
    setletters(letters=>letters.filter(item => item.letter != letters[0].letter));
    let randomnumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
    if(randomnumber!=0){
        randomnumber--;
    }
    setarrnumber(randomnumber);
    upplevel(randomnumber);
    setcounter(counter => counter+10);
}





 const upplevel=(index=arrnumber)=>{
    let answers=[];
    answers.push(letters[index][1]);

    console.log(arrnumber);
    // console.log(answers);
    setoption1(answers[0]);

}
```

like thisss

Comment: State updates are asynchronous to the current executed function. You will always get the old state value.

Answer (score 0):

By using async await,you can fix this issue

```
 const addscore=async()=>{
   await setletters(letters=>letters.filter(item => item.letter != 
   letters[0].letter));
   let randomnumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
   if(randomnumber!=0){
      randomnumber--;
   }
  setarrnumber(randomnumber);
  upplevel(randomnumber);
  setcounter(counter => counter+10);
}
```

Comment: If setletters comes from useState then it would not return a promise and your answer would not work

Answer (score 0):

If you call setLetters it is not mutating letters so letters will have it's new value on next render and not on the next line of executing code. It has nothing to do with setter being async but is because when you use a state setter the state value becomes a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

You can do something like this:

```
const addscore = () => {
  const newLetters = letters.filter(
    (item) => item.letter !== letters[0].letter
  )
  setletters(newLetters);
  let randomnumber = Math.floor(
    Math.random() * newLetters.length
  );
  if (randomnumber != 0) {
    randomnumber--;
  }
  setarrnumber(randomnumber);
  upplevel(randomnumber);
  setcounter((counter) => counter + 10);
};
```